# Arduino and iPhone connection with Bluetooth 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, arduino

I would like to build an app that requires `bluetooth connection`. The Bluetooth `HC05 module` is connected to Arduino. I want to know what framework (or other related things) that I need to build an app that can connect to this Bluetooth module.

Still have no idea how to start. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately the answer might be "you can't do that".

iOS only supports the following Bluetooth profiles: HFP, PBAP, A2DP, AVRCP, PAN, HID and MAP. None of those can be used inside an app to communicate to your Arduino.

For the useful profiles like Serial Port Profile (SPP) and all arbitrary bluetooth communication you have to add an authentication chip to your Arduino. Unfortunately you can't buy these chips unless you have a [MFi membership](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). And you won't get into the MFi program unless you are a company with a concrete product (mass market scale) in mind.

Fortunately, we now have Bluetooth Low Energy. Bluetooth LE can easily be used in iOS apps, without all the MFi hassle. So you should get a Bluetooth 4.0 module for your Arduino.

The framework that is used for Bluetooth 4.0 communication is called CoreBluetooth. You will find documentation, sample code and WWDC videos in the [iOS Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreBluetooth). Start with the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257)